# Object not appearing after a certain amount of time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, flower

So I put the object in the scene and then I made it "invisible" (deactivate if you will) from the inspector (the checkmark box next to the object's name) and after waiting 8 seconds it doesn't become visible. I am using Unity 2d and C#.

I have the game start paused for three seconds then plays after that which works. The first script is that one. The item is supposed to reappear after 8 seconds so after the game resumes, which doesn't work.

```
  //delay before level starts script

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class countDown : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject CountDown;


  private void Start()
 {
    StartCoroutine("StartDelay");

  }

  void Update()
 {

    }
  IEnumerator StartDelay()
  {
     Time.timeScale = 0;
     float pauseTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + 3f;
      while (Time.realtimeSinceStartup < pauseTime)
         yield return 0;
     CountDown.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     Time.timeScale = 1;
 }

 {




//script for the flower to appear
 IEnumerator Start()
  {
    print(Time.time);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(8);
    print(Time.time);
    flowerInScene.gameObject.SetActive(true);
  }

  [SerializeField] Transform flowerInScene;
 }
```

Comment: I just tried your code and it works. Make sure you disabled the game object not it's sprite renderer in the inspector. Btw i am not sure if turning Start() method into a numerator is a good idea, you should probably  make a seperate numerator and start it in Start() function.

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK my game starts paused could that be messing it up?

Comment: Am not sure if scripts on an unactive gameobject would be registered to the start event.

Comment: @Leo Oh I see.  Could be why it worked for the other person and not for me then.  Is it possible to fix that while still keeping the pause in the game?  The pause only lasts a few seconds.

Comment: Just update your question to be more explicit about what you are actually trying to do, so we can help you out!

Comment: @Leo should I make a new question or update this one?

Comment: @Kris Just update it!

Comment: @Leo  Updated it

Comment: Your code is not working. Please fix it

Comment: @derHugo Yeah but how do I fix it?  Another person said he got it working but that was without the pause at the start of the level.

Comment: I'm not speaking of the functionality but your provided code example per se won't even compile since there is an additional `{` and you have a `void Start()` and an `IEnumerator Start()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't really get your two methods called `Start`

You can simply call a `StartCoroutine` at the end of another Coroutine so you can chain them together (though there are surely better ways to do what you want in general):

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class CountDown : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject CountDownObject;
    public GameObject flowerObject;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Delay());
    }

    private IEnumerator Delay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        HideCountdown();
        StartCoroutine(FlowerDelay());
    }

    private void HideCountdown()
    {
        CountDownObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private IEnumerator FlowerDelay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(8);
        ShowFlower();
    }

    private void ShowFlower()
    {
        flowerObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

---

I personaly don't like Coroutines .. they are not so easy to debug sometimes. I would prefer doing something like this with simple timers (though in the first moment it does look worse). Advantage is I can now directly watch the timer count down in the inspector:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SimpleCountDown : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("The Objects")]
    public GameObject CountDownObject;
    public GameObject FlowerObject;

    [Header("Settings")]
    // Here you can adjust the delay times
    public float StartOffset = 3;
    public float FlowerOffset = 8;

    [Header("Debug")]
    public float startTimer;
    public float flowerTimer;

    public bool isStartDelay;
    public bool isFlowerDelay;

    private void Start()
    {
        startTimer = StartOffset;
        flowerTimer = FlowerOffset;
        isStartDelay = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isStartDelay && !isFlowerDelay) return;

        if (isStartDelay)
        {
            startTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (startTimer <= 0)
            {
                HideCountdown();
                isStartDelay = false;
                isFlowerDelay = true;
            }
        }

        if (isFlowerDelay)
        {
            flowerTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (flowerTimer <= 0)
            {
                ShowFlower();
                isFlowerDelay = false;
                this.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void HideCountdown()
    {
        CountDownObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void ShowFlower()
    {
        FlowerObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm what means `none of those worked`? Any errors? I tested both and they do work ... Can you tell me where you attached the component? It may not be on FlowerObject nor on CountDownObject of course! Did you reference both objects? In the second one could you see the timers counting down or what happened?